# vCard credentials, accreditation and associations

Tags: outlook, vcf-vcard

I'm generating some vCards for employees in my company which will be served over the web. Most of the individuals are licensed professionals. I would like to include their accreditation, associations, license numbers, etc... in their vCards.

I've been using RFC6350 and its examples as a guide. There is a specific example in [sec 6.2.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6350#section-6.2.2) that pretty much what I want. According to the RFC's special note, the 4th and 5th elements should contain honorific prefix and suffix. I'm not sure my desired usage fits this description, however in their example, it is used in this way.

Example from RFC: `N:Stevenson;John;Philip,Paul;Dr.;Jr.,M.D.,A.C.P.`

The problem I'm having:

When the vCard is imported into Outlook, Outlook seems to parse the N: field to populate its internal fields:
`N:{last name};{first name};{middle names};{prefix};{suffix}`

When I look at the contact properties the suffix is actually being stored as the "Generation" Property.

After saving the vCard, Outlook seems to calculate the "Display as" property by combining {first name} {middle name} {last name} {generation}, which potentially creates excessively long "display as" names. So, using the RFC's example, Outlook will generate an email addressed to `"John Philip,Paul Stevenson Jr.,M.D.,A.C.P. (test@example.com)" <test@example.com>`. In my case: `"Example User, AIA, NCARB, SEI, LEED GREEN ASSOCIATE(test@example.com)" <test@example.com>`

**My question is: Is there a more appropriate vCard field to store credentials that I am missing, which will not pollute Outlook's display as field OR is there a way to supply a custom "Display as" property in the .vcf that Outlook will pick up on?**

I'm testing in Outlook 2016

Comment: Why not simply reset the ContactItem.FileAs property after vCard is imported?

Comment: I'm going to be serving these vCards as downloads on a website. I will update question.